# Explore recursively an Object with Underscore and convert field type

Tags: javascript, regex, underscore.js

I'm working with some custom jSON objects.

I'm trying to explore this whole object, and to change field type.

For exemple, real_id or clean_id and even temperature need to be converted as Integer.

To deal with that, I started to make a function which is very simple :

```
var reg = /^\d+$/;
_.each(myObject, function(val, key) {
    myObject[key] = reg.test(val) ? parseInt(val) :val;
});
```

I got several needs :

1. it will check every field one by one on the first level, but if `myObject` has elements which themselves include object or array of object, my `_.each` won't explore them.
2. For now it can detect integer thanks to the regex, and convert them to Integer but what if I need to convert a float?
3. If I find null I need to set it to 0 instead

On my exemple below,

Exemple of Sample of jSON object :

```
myObject = {
    "real_name": "Test",
    "maker": "Jean-Paul",
    "company": "",
    "real_id": "646402",
    "clean_id": "152691",
    "year": 2013,
    "type": "Red real",
    "available_for_order": 0,
    "level": null,
    "bio": null,
    "temperature": "15",
    "potential": "3",
    "country_code": "USA",
    "coord_lng": "2.7014349999999",
    "coord_lat": "42.717317",
    "real_description": [
        {
            "comment": "Real good stuff",
            "lang": "it",
            "video_end": null,
            "video_id": null,
            "video_start": null,
            "video_url": null
        },
        {
            "comment": "Awesome and cheap stuff",
            "lang": "en",
            "video_end": null,
            "video_id": null,
            "video_start": null,
            "video_url": null
        }
    ],
    "full_description": [
        {
            "description": "Long description",
            "lang": "fr"
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "lang": "en"
        }
    ],
    "list": [
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "656732",
            "year": "1"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "330381",
            "year": "2008"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 20,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "11453216",
            "year": "2010"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "11497420",
            "year": "2011"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "1",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 10,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "11506715",
            "year": "2012"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "1",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 10,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "11458207",
            "year": "2013"
        }
    ],
    "check_list": [
        "3",
        "8",
        "9",
        "10",
        "14"
    ],
    "image_src": "791330_31odFZZoM2_JqkCPJGHXa_4500x1000.jpeg"
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Hey, I edited my comment, could you check and see if it works for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need, in my opinion, is a simple example of recursion, Lodash isn't required...

NOTE: You're using a regex that matches only string that starts and ends with a one or more occurrence of digit...
So, instead of using parseInt or parseFloat, you should use **Number** to cast values!

In Javascript Number is the constructor of the type Number, but, if called without the **new** operator, performs a basic Casting.
It returns NaN when the casting is unsatisfable, so, using the **or** operator we can keep the original value!

Hope Helps...

```js
var myObject = {
    "real_name": "Test",
    "maker": "Jean-Paul",
    "company": "",
    "real_id": "646402",
    "clean_id": "152691",
    "year": 2013,
    "type": "Red real",
    "available_for_order": 0,
    "level": null,
    "bio": null,
    "temperature": "15",
    "potential": "3",
    "country_code": "USA",
    "coord_lng": "2.7014349999999",
    "coord_lat": "42.717317",
    "real_description": [
        {
            "comment": "Real good stuff",
            "lang": "it",
            "video_end": null,
            "video_id": null,
            "video_start": null,
            "video_url": null
        },
        {
            "comment": "Awesome and cheap stuff",
            "lang": "en",
            "video_end": null,
            "video_id": null,
            "video_start": null,
            "video_url": null
        }
    ],
    "full_description": [
        {
            "description": "Long description",
            "lang": "fr"
        },
        {
            "description": "",
            "lang": "en"
        }
    ],
    "list": [
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "656732",
            "year": "1"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "330381",
            "year": "2008"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 20,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "11453216",
            "year": "2010"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 0,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "11497420",
            "year": "2011"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "0",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "1",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 10,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "11506715",
            "year": "2012"
        },
        {
            "available_for_order": "1",
            "capacity": "4500",
            "conciergerie": "0",
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "price": 10,
            "quantity": 0,
            "retail_price": 0,
            "real_id": "11458207",
            "year": "2013"
        }
    ],
    "check_list": [
        "3",
        "8",
        "9",
        "10",
        "14"
    ],
    "image_src": "791330_31odFZZoM2_JqkCPJGHXa_4500x1000.jpeg"
};


function recurse(obj) {
  for(var key in obj) {
    if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) { continue; }
    
    if('object' === typeof obj[key]) {
      recurse(obj[key]);
    } else {
      console.log(key, obj[key], typeof obj[key],  ' ==> ', typeof (Number(obj[key]) || obj[key]));
      obj[key] = Number(obj[key]) || obj[key];
    }
  
  }
}

recurse(myObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var parseObjectProperties = function (obj) {
    _.each(obj, function(val, key) {
        if (typeof(key) === 'object') {
            parseObjectProperties(key);
        } else {
            if (getType(val) === 'float') {
                myObject[key] = parseFloat(val);
            } else if (getType(val) === 'int') {
                myObject[key] = parseInt(val);
            } else if (val === null) {
                myObject[key] = 0;
            }
        }
    });
};

var getType = function(input) {
    var match = (/[\d]+(\.[\d]+)?/).exec(input);
    if (match ) {
       if (match [1]) { 
           return 'float'; 
       } else { 
           return 'int'; 
       }          
    }
    return 'string';
}

exploreObject(myObject);
```